# broadcastRecevier onreceive handling content of the message

Tags: android, android-activity, broadcastreceiver

i want to pass some information from the received message when i receive it such as the content of the message or the source number of it, and i want to put that information in a button on when a certain condition is true not oncreate, am building messaging application so i want to store my received message in "inbox" how can i do that?
Ps. my onreceive method in a class extends broadcastReceiver and my other class extends activity
thanks in advance!
here is my first class where i extends broadcastreceiver

```
public class Re extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
 {
 Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();       
SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
 String address="";
    String body="";
    long time = 0;
    if (bundle != null)
    {
        //---retrieve the SMS message received---
        Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
        msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
 address= msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
            body=msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
            time=msgs[i].getTimestampMillis();
}   

}
```

and here is my second class where i extends activity

```
public class ThirdView extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.third);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, be a bit more "specific". What is your problem? Retrieving values from broadcasted intent? Updating button on runtime? Or else? And maybe provide some code how you tried to do that, It will help people to help you ;).

Comment: hey Tomasz Gawel thanks for replaying, i'll provide some code, my problem: i want to make like an inbox design or something like it, when a receive a message and a specific condition is true, ex: if the source number of the message == "john", create a button and the text of the button the details of the message that received.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have access to your activity from Receiver's onReceive - then you should define BroadcastReceiver as inner class of the Actvity and register it programmatically (in onStart method, and unregister in onStop);

```
public class ThirdView extends Activity {

    private static final IntentFilter intentFilter = 
        new IntentFilter("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED");

    TextButton myButton;

    BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            SmsMessage[] messages;
            //read parse pdus data from intent and pupulate messages array
            //...

            //update the button
            if(messages.length > 0) {
                myButton.setText(messages[0].getOriginatingAddress());
            }
        }

    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.third);
        myButton = (TextButton) findViewByiD(R.id.myButton);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        registerReceiver(receiver, intentFilter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        unregisterReceiver(receiver);
        super.onStop();
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks you so much for your helpful answer, the button created when i receive a message and the source address in it, but the button didn't saved like when i hit back and open it again the button gone, and when i receive another message it doesn't create another button.. am sorry if am asking too much its just my first try on android development. thanks again

Comment: if so your broadcast receiver should save the sms in local database, and then your activity shoud render list of messages stored in db. In this case you should come back to reciever registered in manifest not programatically. the receiver should start the service which would save the messages and broadcasted another intent (locally in your app) to let the activity know that new messages has been saved. the activity would listen to that intent just like the activity above listens to the sms received intent, as the messages are in your apps db then you can retrieve them from db by id.

Comment: thanks a lot for the valuable information i'll try it for sure and give you my feedback!